# removeClass is permanent

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have a generic class which I want to add to a div on click.
On the click it first will remove that class from any elements it has been added to, and then add it to the clicked element.

My problem is that on the second click it will not add the class.

You can see the result here - http://jsfiddle.net/47FPa/2/

```
.hilite{background-color:#d5d5d5; padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius:6px;margin-right:8px;}

<ul>
<li id="a"><a href="#a">Subject A</a></li>
<li id="b"><a href="#b">Subject B</a></li>
 <div class="a">
<a id="a"></a>
<h2>
    Subject A 
</h2>
    <p> Lorem ipsum eros nostrud inermis eam ei, ius ut noster ceteros, voluptua sensibus mnesarchum his et. Tamquam discere constituto his no. Viderer quaeque rationibus no nec, vel at esse accusamus, in has debet vituperata.</p>
</div>
<div class="b">
<a id="b"></a>
<h2>
    Subject B
</h2>
    <p>Vix ei amet fuisset, ad dolor nusquam accumsan pri, per erant interesset at. Ea aliquip elaboraret percipitur eos.</p>
```

```
<script> $('#a').click(function(){
$( 'div.hilite' ).removeClass();
$( 'div.a' ).addClass( 'hilite' );
});</script>

<script> $('#b').click(function(){
$( 'div.hilite' ).removeClass();
$( 'div.b' ).addClass( 'hilite' );
});</script>
```

Comment: ID's have to be unique.

Comment: And you have some invalid HTML as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47FPa/14/) should work perfect.

```
<script> $('#a').click(function(){
    $( '.hilite' ).removeClass('hilite');
$( '#div_a' ).toggleClass('hilite');
});</script>

<script> $('#b').click(function(){
$( '.hilite' ).removeClass('hilite');
$( '#div_b' ).toggleClass('hilite');
});</script>
```

I have also just added id's to your div's (see fiddle).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<a id="a"></a>` and `<a id="b"></a>`.

Because IDs must be unique. And I think these tags are of no use as  click event is not attached to these.

Try:

```
$('#a').click(function(){
    $( '.hilite' ).removeClass('hilite');
    $( 'div.a' ).addClass( 'hilite' );
});

$('#b').click(function(){
    $( '.hilite' ).removeClass('hilite');
    $( 'div.b' ).addClass( 'hilite' );
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/47FPa/6/)

Comment: Thanks to all.  The fiddles all work.  The reason for the anchor IDs is that the page contains many paragraphs and I want to also jump to that section from the link.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps..

Replace your script with this

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a').click(function(){
        $( 'body' ).find('.hilite').removeClass('hilite');
        $( 'div.a' ).addClass( 'hilite' );
    });
    $('#b').click(function(){
        $( 'body' ).find('.hilite').removeClass('hilite');
        $( 'div.b' ).addClass( 'hilite' );
    });
})
</script>
```

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47FPa/15/)